# When setting an element property, why would I need to change the fontStyle each time?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have take over on development of an application and I am looking at an iOS label custom renderer. I have the code for that below.

What I would like to know is if anyone can see a reason why the SetTextFontStyle method is called for when the textColor and textProperty are changed.

Also is there a way that I can use this custom rendered for more than one font type?  I want to be able to pass in a font type to the renderer if possible.

```
public class LabelBodyCustomRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    public LabelBodyCustomRenderer()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
            Control.Font = UIFont.GetPreferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyle.Body);

    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextColorProperty.PropertyName)
            SetFontTextStyle();
        else if (e.PropertyName == Label.FontProperty.PropertyName)
            SetFontTextStyle();
        else if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == Label.FormattedTextProperty.PropertyName)
            SetFontTextStyle();
    }

    void SetFontTextStyle()
    {
        Control.Font = UIFont.GetPreferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyle.Body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at, or just use the [FormsCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/FormsCommunityToolkit). It has an Effect for a Label that does this for you. Look at it [here](https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/FormsCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/src/Effects/Effects.iOS/Effects/Label/LabelCustomFont.cs)

Comment: I clicked on the most important link on that page "download sample app" and got a 404 page not found :-(

Comment: Will have a look. Thanks

Comment: Awkward.. It seems the sample app is [here](https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/FormsCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/Samples). If you still have any questions, let me know. Coincidentally I implemented this label effect

Comment: Thanks very much Gerald